# Триггер не отображается в Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

Триггер выполняется, без проблем удаляется запросом, а папка Database Triggers пустая(Refresh делал), версия 12. Баг или я чего-то не понимаю?

И еще, где, собственно, в Object Explorer найти таблицу sys.triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте внимательно, до прояснения: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189799.aspx

Database triggers - это триггеры уровня базы данных (DDL). Вы, скорее всего, создаете триггер на таблице - это триггер DML и показывается он в ветке от соответствующей таблицы.

sys.triggers - это системная таблица. Она если и показывается, то в ветке системных таблиц (в Management Studio под системные отдельная ветка выделена), или не показывается вообще - просто делайте запрос к ней и получайте нужные данные.